# How to force the user to stop typing in UITextField but allow backspacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that my user uses to type out tags. I need to be able to *at a very specific time* -  stop my user from continuing to type in the keyboard that is presented by default with UITextFields. However, I need my user to still be allowed to hit the backspace button on the iOS keyboard so that they can try and type a word that will fit.

A couple VERY important things to keep in mind:

1. The `UITextField` should not be frozen due to a maximum amount of characters, because I am determining when the textField should be frozen based off of UIViews that I am adding to the screen for the tags
2. The user still should be able to backspace
3. The keyboard should not be dismissed
4. The textField should not be disabled

I have tried setting the `textField.enabled = NO`, but once again, I need to still be able to use the textField, I just simply need to freeze the typing and force the user to backspace, not allowing andy characters to be added to the `textField`.

Comment: in shouldChangeCharactersInRange: method check the parameter "string" length if it is 0  than you can consider it as back space so return YES else it is a character return NO

Comment: Thank you I was actually trying to figure that part out. I think that's exactly what I need for desired behavior

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like below

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString: (NSString*) string {

  NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString: string];

  if([text length] > MAX_LENGTH)
       return NO;
  else 
       return YES;

 }
```

EDIT1:
 To this delegate method get called, set the textfield's delegate.
In this case, you can use it as

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

In your viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear.

Comment: Don't forget to give your textfield.delegate=self;

Comment: if the textfield pre populated with more than MAX_Length than the above code will not work to delete or remove the text using backspace

Comment: @ismail: No, it's not that, when you do back spacing after reaching MAX_LENTH, the new text length become (MAX_LENGTH - 1), that's why we  replacing textField.text with the edit(backspace) in the first line of the method.

Comment: @Suresh if we are typing than it is ok if we set text=@"something" in this case if the data in the textfield is greater than the MAX_LENGTH than your code will not wok to delete the beyond characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // Prevent crashing undo bug – see note below.
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    if(textField == self.yourTextField)
    {
        return newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Back space will work even if the textfield pre populated with more than MAX_Length text

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString: (NSString*) string {
  NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString: string];

NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString: string];
if([text length] > MAX_LENGTH && string.length>0)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
}
```